# Can connect JConsole remotely but not VisualVM

Tags: jmx, visualvm, jconsole, jvisualvm

I'm trying to profile a remote Tomcat and I'm able to connect to it with JConsole, but fail with VisualVM. I set up a proxy with ssh:

```
ssh -luser -D 9898 -Nf example.com
```

And with these configurations in tomcat7.conf:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3333 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=example.com
```

With this options JConsole works perfectly, but VisualVM doesn't. Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

A year late, but in case anybody else might find it useful. This was not a problem with Java 7, but I started seeing this with Java 8. Ever since I've been using the below two commands to successfully connect to both jconsole and jvisualvm:

`jconsole -J-DsocksProxyHost=localhost -J-DsocksProxyPort=<SOCKS_PORT> service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://<REMOTE_HOST:JMX_PORT>/jmxrmi

jvisualvm -J-DsocksProxyHost=localhost -J-DsocksProxyPort=<SOCKS_PORT> --openjmx <REMOTE_HOST>`

In your case SOCKS_PORT would be 9898 and JMX_PORT would be 3333.